# Doubts regarding 'quadratic field can be obtained by adjoining square root'

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This is from Artin's *Algebra* (2nd ed.), Proposition 15.3.3:

> [image]
>   [image]

I think that we showed in the first para of the proof that degree two extension can be obtained by adjoining a square root. Then, why they put 'conversely' almost at the end of the para?

How do we know that $\sqrt D$ indeed exists?

Comment: It says so in the statement, "if $\delta$ is an element of a field extension of $F$", so we already assume that it exists. Recall also that $[F : F(\delta)]$ is the dimension of $F(\delta)$ over $F$ as a vector space, so indeed we get a quadratic extension this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first paragraph, they show that a degree-2 extension can be obtained by adjoining a root of *some* quadratic polynomial (not necessarily a square root). Then in the second paragraph they show how the same extension can be obtained just by adjoining a square root (a square root of $D$).

The two square roots of $D$ in $K$ (and thus the two possible choices for $\delta$) are given by
$$
\pm(2\alpha + b) 
$$
You can square this yourself (and simplify using $\alpha^2 = -b\alpha - c$) and see that we do indeed get $D = b^2 - 4c$ as a result.

Finally, the "conversely" part is about showing that adjoining a square root (which is not already in $F$) always gives a degree-2 extension.

Comment: Thank you so much.Will you please shed some light about statement in second para of proof : Then $\delta$ is in $K$, $\delta^2$ is in $F$, and because $\alpha$ is in field $F(\delta)$, $\delta$ generates $K$ over $F$. I can't quite understand what they want to say by 'because $\alpha$ is in field $F(\delta)$, $\delta$ generates $K$ over $F$'.

Comment: @Silent Using the expression for $\delta$ I described in my answer, it is clear that $\delta\in K$. However, we also know that $\alpha\in F(\delta)$, since $\alpha = \frac12(-b\pm\delta)$. So $F(\delta) = F(\alpha)$. The phrase "$\delta$ generates $K$" is just another way of saying "$F(\delta) = K$": Using only $\delta$ (and the field $F$ itself) we can generate all of $K$.